# Wit.ai differences between Trait - Free Text - Keyword and Intent/entities

Tags: node.js, wit.ai, wit-ai

It's a mess in my head right now. I've seen this video tutorial to understand Wit.ai logic : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yLAHVPaHWFA

It's a really good video for basic training. But I can't still understand the logic.
I want to create a story like that Human(H) / Robot(R):
**(H) Hello

(R) Hello human, you can choose A action or B action

(H) A action

(R) Ok human, this is A action** 

It's really simple but I don't know what to declare in "understanding" section.
1 - Do I have to create a "Say Hello" intent
2 - If yes, Do I have to create an "hello" entity and feed it with other salutations like "Hi", "yo", "What's up?", ... 
3 - Do I have to create a "choose action" intent or it's just one intent for one story ? This is exactly what I don't understand. 
4 - If yes, A&B action are free-text like ("An hotel", "a restaurant"). How can I teach the bot to recognized them ?
I just need some enlightening about those points ! It's really hard for me to translate and understand correctly. Thank you for you help !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may declare a "greeting" intent(Intents are just user-created entities). After that, you can validate(feed) it with many other words like "*Hey buddy, Sup bud, Hellloooo, Hi bot, etc*". Also, you can give values to that intent such as Negative or Positive values.

For instance:

" *`Hey dumb f*`* " >> **"greeting" Intent + Negative value** ❌

" *`Hi brother!`* " >> **"greeting" Intent + Positive value** ✅

So that you can decide between:

"*`Language, please... Anyway. Hey {user_name}`*"

or

"*`Hey {user_name} ! :) Really nice to see you here !`* "

to respond to the user's simple hi text.

Other than that:

**(R)** *`Hello human, you can choose A action or B action`*

**(H)** *`A action`*

**(R)** *`Ok human, this is A action`*

This type of interaction needs the usage of **/converse API**

https://wit.ai/docs/recipes#converse-link

In this above link go down to the **"Handle yes/no answers"** section.

Also, you can use Quick Replies for letting the user choose between the A Action or B Action. Quick Replies are really useful for this type of interactions.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/send-api-reference/quick-replies

Comment: Thank you for your great answer !